# Swift: How can I retain data and displaying after changing to other view and change back to current view?

Tags: ios, swift, mobile-development

I'm wondering how can I retain the displaying after first change to another view and then change back to current view?

Specifically,as below. My problem is when I click `Histoty`  button I switch to another page, which has the exactly same three button. and when I switch back to `current` page the table data is lost. And what I want is show the table data without any data reload. Please help me out. Thanks.

[image]

Comment: I believe your problem can be solved with a [singleton](https://thatthinginswift.com/singletons/).

Comment: Try to save it in an array then use it when going back.

Answer (score 0):

Best way to maintain the data in their respective data models and reload the data when you switch to respective page.

Based on the information provided, you can design your data model to be something like,

```
class StockInfo {
    var name: String?
    var symbol: String?
    var lastPrice: Double?

    //define additional properties...
}
```

Note: You can use structure or class type based on your requirement